# How to publish Xamarin iOS mono application to iTunesConnect prerelease for beta testing?

Tags: xamarin, app-store-connect, testflight

Now when TestFlight is integrated with iTunesConnect, how can I publish my iOS application to the former TestFlight for beta testing?

When I try using the "Publish to TestFlight" option from Xamarin Studio, I'm getting an error:

Uploading to TestFlightApp.com...
Upload succeeded

Unhandled error while uploading

Answer (score 0):

The "Publish To Test Flight" feature in Xamarin was nothing more than an encapsulation of manually uploading your *.ipa file to www.testflightapp.com.  I personally though it was rather useless and it was zero effort just to manually do it myself.  But that's irrelevant.

As you know, Apple has acquired Test Flight, and has now shut down www.testflightapp.com.  Since that's what Xamarin depended on, that no longer works and you'll get errors.  What you have to do now is use Test Flight though iTunes Connect.  Unfortunately, it won't be as easy as it used to be, but is really not that much difficult.  It does require some upfront work though.  You can learn how to do that here:

[TestFlight Through iTunes Connect](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html)